# Condition inside getAll for compound index

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

what will be the equivalent query for

```
select * from emails where to="someemail" and from="some@email"
```

need to use get instead of filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getAll`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_all/) is your friend:

> `table.getAll([key, key2...], [, {index:'id'}]) → selection`

Assuming that you have a compound key index, something like:

```js
r.db('emails')
    .table('emails')
    .indexCreate('conversation', [r.row('from'), r.row('to')])
```

you can easily get all emails:

```js
r.db('emails')
    .table('emails')
    .getAll(['some@email', 'someemail'], {index: 'conversation'})
```

For example, having the following dataset

```js
r.db('emails')
    .table('emails')
    .insert([
        {from: 'foo@mail', to: 'bar@mail', text: 'Hi Bar!'},
        {from: 'bar@mail', to: 'foo@mail', text: 'Hi Foo!'},
        {from: 'foo@mail', to: 'bar@mail', text: 'Bye Bar!'},
        {from: 'bar@mail', to: 'foo@mail', text: 'Bye Foo!'}
    ])
```

that's queried with the following query

```js
r.db('emails')
   .table('emails')
   .getAll(['foo@mail', 'bar@mail'], {index: 'conversation'})
   .pluck('text')
```

will produce:

```js
[
    {"text": "Bye Bar!"},
    {"text": "Hi Bar!"}
]
```

(The order above is undefined.)